# Why does the term "epicondyle" often refer to either of the two at the elbow end of the humerus?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, history

Why does the term "epicondyle" often refer to either of the two at the elbow end of the humerus?

[Example](https://www.google.com/search?q=Epicondyle):

[image]

I understand that epicondyle means near a condyle, but there are several [condyles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condyle_(anatomy)) in the human body:

> - On the femur, in the knee joint:
>
>   - Medial condyle
>   - Lateral condyle
> - On the tibia, in the knee joint:
>
>   - Medial condyle
>   - Lateral condyle
> - On the humerus, in the elbow joint:
>
>   - Condyle of humerus (Condylus humeri)
> - On the mandible, in the temporomandibular joint:
>
>   - Mandibular condyle
> - On the occipital bone, in the atlanto-occipital joint:
>
>   - Occipital condyles

Comment: If something is unclear in the question, please explain, I'd be glad to improve it.

Comment: The humerus is the only of those that has a "protuberance"?

Comment: @kmm That would indeed explain. But is it true that the humerus is the only of those that has a protuberance?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [lateral epicondyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_epicondyle_of_the_humerus) and a [medial epicondyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_epicondyle_of_the_humerus) of the humerus. "*Epi-*" is a Latin root meaning "near". Both epicondyles are near the condyle of the humerus.

Comment: Thanks. "Near the condyle of the humerus" -> Why the humerus in particular? I understand the "near the condyle" part.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - If you understand the " 'near the condyle' part", you have your answer. What more do you expect? Are you asking how many epicondyles there are? Are you asking what the equivalents are on the femur? Clarify, if you will. Otherwise be nice and accept (or at least upvote) this correct answer!

Comment: @anongoodnurse there are more than one condyle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condyle_(anatomy) . Why the humerus in particular? Just curious. Calm down. Why did you downvote the question?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - You're welcome. I also voted to close as unclear. Always happy to do my part to make a site - and its questions and answers - better. (Ha! you edited your comment. I DV'd because your question is unclear. That's one of the DV reasons (hover over the button and you'll see.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse what is unclear in the question?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the entire question is unclear. If you actually click on some of the links in the Google search you show, you'll see that there are several epicondyles - a lateral and a medial on both the humerus and the femur - and they are referred to as "the [lateral/medial] epicondyle **of the** [humerus/femur]", meaning the bone itself is referenced in the name. Google doesn't give a link as to where its definition comes from, but I suspect they said "especially of the humerus" because of lateral epicondylitis or "tennis elbow". You need to look at multiple sources to verify something.

Comment: @MattDMo unclear isn't the same as incorrect

Comment: @Franck I will admit I was unsure exactly what you were asking when I provided this answer. I will happily delete the answer but I still don't really understand what your question is - would you mind clarifying?

Comment: @HarryVervet "Both epicondyles are near the condyle of the humerus." ->  how about the [Medial epicondyle of the femur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_epicondyle_of_the_femur)? My question is: Why does the term “epicondyle” often refer to epicondyle of the humerus, whereas there are other epicondyles in the human body.